# conflicts in Git feature branches, how to detect them early

Tags: git

With developing Java with Git, we have the frequent problem that different people change the same classes in different feature branches, which results in merge conflicts.  While these problems are inevitable to some point, we would like to detect these problems early, so people can talk and align.

I see two possible solutions here: best practices (like looking at other peoples branches) and tool support.  If I miss some best practices, so please point me to some document.  If there are tools (you add branches to a list and get an email in case of possible conflicts), please tell me.

Comment: My opinion is that frequent conflict between branches are caused by bad modularization of units between dev teams

Comment: I admit, our code is monolithic and not well modularized, owing in part to its legacy. Rewrite is not an option. But we do have some separation, in particular between "infrastructure" and "problem specific" parts. Frequently, one has to change the infrastructure to get more precision/information in some aspect. If two developers do that in the same area in parallel - dang.

Comment: You probably should look into breaking down your features so that the feature branches only live for a day or two.

Answer (score 1):

That's similar to continuous integration.

You could have whatever build-system you use for continuous integration (teamcity, jenkins) try to merge branches every day/hour and send an e-mail when it failed to do it automatically.

Comment: Well, not exactly.  While working on complex feature branches, you have intermediate states that do not compile and/or could not be merged. Nevertheless, you'd like to know of potential problems. In fact, such a "problem notice" would be the more helpful the longer your feature branch cannot be merged.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to **rebase** your branches frequently.

Once another developer has merged his branch in master (or another common dev branch), you can rebase your current branch with master and thus deal with the conflicts at this moment.

Another good practice is to have short-lived branches that will allow to see conflicts rapidly.

You can also have the developers open a merge request as soon as they start to work on their branches, that way, other developers can see if they are working on the same files and anticipate conflicts.